# ColdFusion Component to Variable

Tags: variables, coldfusion, components, invoke

I have a coldfusion component that is uneditable, only echos strings, and does not return a variable(and there is no return * statement). How can I grab this echoed string and place it in a variable before it is displayed directly on screen?
So :

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Helpz">
<cffunction name="OutputString" returnType="void" output="yes">
    I love Stack overflow
</cffunction>
```

The outputted string needs to be stored into a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFSavecontent is what you need.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myString"><cfset object.outputString() /></cfsavecontent>
```

Then you can do anything you want with #myString#.

Answer (score 4):

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
<cfset myComponent.outputString()>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a better practice to avoid that kind of output from within a function. An alternative solution would be:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Helpz">
<cffunction name="getString" returnType="string" output="no">
    <cfset var myString = "">
    <cfsavecontent variable="myString">I love Stack overflow</cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn myString>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

and then in you're template or wherever:

```
<cfoutput>#myCfc.getString()#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Everything can be done with better practices, but that does not help me when I don't have access to edit the function.